# Efficient way to create a specific sized Lua table filled with zero?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Is there an easier way to create a specific sized Lua table filled with zero without having to use loop to fill the table manually?

The only solution I know is like the following:

```
local t = {}
local size = 100
for i = 1, size do
  t[i] = 0
end
```

Would there be more efficient and easier way?

Comment: Use metamethod `__index` to emulate zeroes.

Comment: You can also use `t[i] or 0` when reading from the table, if your table does not store `false`.

Comment: ... if your table does not store `false` and `nil`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: You can't store `nil` in a table. That's equivalent to not having a value, and it will change the length of the array.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Sometimes you really need to store `nil` in a table.  Yes, that's not distinguishable from removing the value, but that's just a terminology question :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: It's not a "terminology question" to the `#` operator. Or `ipairs`. Or pretty much every aspect of Lua. Storing `nil` in an array entry makes the array *shorter*. You can maintain a separate length count, but as far as the regular Lua system is concerned, the array just got shorter.

Comment: @NicolBolas - `Storing nil in an array entry makes the array shorter.` - Yes.  But we are talking about tables.  Not about arrays or sequences.  Please note that OP never says "array".  And storing `nil` in a table is ok (if destination side knows the table key where it should read the value from).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: So, what exactly is a "sized Lua table" if not an array? A Lua table that has a size... is an array. The OP may not be using strict Lua terminology, but from the actual terms used, and the *example code* that shows building an array, it's pretty clear what's being discussed.

Comment: @NicolBolas - `So, what exactly is a "sized Lua table" if not an array?` Does a dictionary have a size?  Of course yes.  For example, a size may be a number of elements in a dictionary (the most natural definition).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: OK, let's be pedantic then. Lua doesn't have a "dictionary". A Lua table can have a size, but Lua only defines a that represents the size of the array part of the table, not the key/value-pair part. Furthermore, even if you invent a definition for "size" that relates to the key/value pair part of a table, if you assign any value in a table to `nil`, then it *will not appear* as part of any Lua construct that could compute the size of the key/value part of the table. So that's two ways that you're wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas - You are confusing `#` operator and actual table size (which consists of array size and hash size).  OP never mentioned `#`, `array` and  `ipairs`.  And most programming languages do have concept of size of an associative array.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: OK, prove to me that when the OP said "sized Lua table", he was *not* talking about an array. Prove to me that when the OP gave an example of inserting elements into an array, he was *not* talking about just an array. Because both of those are perfectly logical conclusions to draw from the available evidence. Your conclusions seem to be drawn based on trying to avoid the obvious interpretation.

Comment: @NicolBolas - `Your conclusions seem to be drawn based on trying to avoid the obvious interpretation.`  Yes, I was trying to avoid your interpretation and insist on my interpretation.  Both interpretations are equally "obvious".  But there is not enough data in the question to deduce which interpretation is closer to OP's intention.  I mean OP might be quite happy with dictionaries.  And you can't disprove this.